# How to create a random 160 bit prime number in C++?

Tags: c++

I am working on a project in school and I need to create a 160 bit value.  I haven't programmed in a while so I can't figure out how I would implement this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try the all new and fancy boost 1.53 multiprecision library. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html

Comment: Checking [this](http://bellard.org/mersenne.html) might help too.

Answer (score 2):

You need a library for big integers (assuming you can't just take a ready-to-use cryptographic library).

First you create a random 160-bit value, not necessarily prime. Depending on the platform, you may use `/dev/random`, `CryptGenRandom`, or some other enthropy source(s), (possible several ones, combined).

Then you increment the value in a loop, applying e.g. [Miller-Rabin (pseudo-)primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) to each candidate, until you find a prime number.